# TextMeshPro Text Overlaps Icon

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have my highscore, when it changes it moves to the left, but i need to move it to the right.
How i could achieve that?

[Here is problem in imgur picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnJTa.png)

I'm using canvas with TextMesPro Text and icon as image
[TextMesPro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zs8X.png)

Comment: Please, edit your question and provide more information about your setup, at least, show the TextMeshPro component...

Comment: What do you mean it "moves to the left"?

Answer (score 0):

Put the text and the icon inside a HorizontalLayoutGroup and add a LayoutElement to both. Set the HorizontalLayoutGroup to control child height/width, child force expand width/height. Set the flexible width to the text (in the LayoutElement) to a very high value. Set the preferred size of the image to the size you want the icon to be. You might also want to add a little bit of spacing to the layout group.